# vscode cpp tool extension alternatives

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

-- I'm looking for a cpp tool extension as substitution of cpp tool comes from Microsoft, because it takes too much ram even I did not do anything, so I only need an extension can help me do go-to definition, any extensions can do this ?
-- I am using ubuntu OS, with gcc.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Clangd](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd) is the way to go.

Comment: thanks, seems only works for clang not gcc

Comment: It works for both. It doesn't matter what compiler you use, since it doesn't interact with it.